# Swift 2.2: Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Tags: swift, swift2, nscoder

I have converted an Objective-C method into Swift. And then, into the Swift code i am getting this error. I have no tied what i have done wrong.

Objective-C Code

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self loadChecklistItems];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Swift 2.2 code

```
convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    if (self.init(coder: aDecoder)) {  // ERROR Here
        self.loadChecklistItems()
    }
}
```

[Here is the screenshot of Swift code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol8y6.png)

Please tell me what i have done wrong and what will be the right code.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990677/how-to-code-initwithcoder-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the initializer directly:

```
convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.loadChecklistItems()
}
```

However, note that your code is making an infinite cycle of calls. Are you sure you don't want to call `super.init(...)`? Also, I think that this is not a *convenience* initializer:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.loadChecklistItems()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That initializer is failable, meaning it can return nil. The syntax for a failable initializer in Swift is:

```
convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {  // Note the question mark after init
```

Additionally, if you call that initializer from within itself, your code will infinitely loop. I think you mean to do:

```
convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)  // call super.init, not self.init
    self.loadChecklistItems()
}
```